# Error while importing Sharepoint site in SP 2010

Tags: site-collection, export, import

I am trying to export a Sharepoint site from one environment to another. The steps I followed are as below

- created the site collection with web application from Sharepoint central admin in the new server.
- exported from older env ( using export command producing .cmp file)
- build the code and deployed the wsp's (using the install and add commands)
- Try importing the site using the import command ( getting the below listed exception thrown)

> Exception thrown:
>
> Import-SPWeb : Could not find WebTemplate AZ.SHAREPOINT.MLZ.SITEDEFINITION#1000
> 0 with LCID 1033.

Please advise me on the above error, on how I could get the template from my older environment and install in lower environment to enable the import to work.

Tried saving the site as template without content (due to size issue) in older env and in restoring in new but that too was throwing an exception like an feature is not activated in new one which was also not found in manage site features of older site.

Any help is highly appreciated, as I am stuck here trying to reproduce the steps in different order and servers.

Comment: Have you tried creating a back up of the site and restoring that to your target location instead of using the export command?  Sp-backup Sp-Restore via power shell.

Comment: looks like the feature you are referring to is a site collection feature instead of site feature!

Comment: @ Vamsi , even in that case is there any option to download the feature like a wsp file and install in other server.

Comment: @ Roland, working on the option of backing up the site and restoring, facing some issue at webpart level, will kepp ya posted ..

Comment: The option of backup and restored worked, thanks Roland

Answer (score 0):

The option of backup and restored worked, thanks Roland.

I had backed up the complete Sharepoint Site from the lower environment and restored the same and with proper account configuration I am able to access my site with the wsp's deployed.